# Java comparing String "sheme or prefix"

Tags: java, string

I don't know for what keywords I have to look for, so maybe you can help me.
I want to check if some String has the right prefix or sheme.

```
public void checkOnlyLetters(String s){
    if(s.equals("OnlyThisPartMattersXXXXX"){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

The XXXXX part is just some numbers that don't matter. So `s` can look like `OnlyThisPartMatter123456678` to be true.

How do can I make this and what's the keyword for this subject?

Comment: `Regular Expression` is the keyword you're looking for. Essentially it's Pattern Matching.

Comment: Please look at the docs for [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's startsWith() method will help you in this case

```
String s = "OnlyThisPartMatter123456678";
if(s.startsWith("OnlyThisPartMatter"){
        doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method startWith() (on string) in if expression to check prefix. Additionally you can use substring() method to extract second part and check if it is number.